# EJB remoting issue in WildFly 16

Tags: wildfly

When I connect from client java application to wildFly remote ejb over SSL, getting this error. 
The client connects to EJB via remoting. The remoting in WildFly is configured with SSLRealm and the HTTPS listener also set with SSLRealm.
The same worked with WF 8.2 and this issue seen after migrating to WF-16.

SSL debug log:

> %% No cached client session update handshake state: client_hello[1]
>   upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
>   *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1583221271 bytes = { 169, 19, 89, 86, 88, 131, 155, 237, 237, 142, 227, 16, 104, 162, 145, 10,
>   46, 109, 215, 68, 16, 53, 154, 91, 112, 216, 168, 160 } Session ID: 
>   {} Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] Compression Methods:  { 0 }
>   Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1,
>   secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1,
>   sect571r1, secp256k1} Extension ec_point_formats, formats:
>   [uncompressed] Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms:
>   SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA,
>   SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA,
>   SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
>   Extension extended_master_secret**
>    XNIO-1 I/O-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 199 XNIO-1 I/O-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1035 check handshake state:
>   server_hello[2]
>    **ServerHello, TLSv1.2 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1583221271 bytes = { 107, 141, 20, 188, 78, 97, 175, 228, 80, 217, 148, 35, 196, 141, 120, 88,
>   110, 219, 94, 135, 8, 172, 103, 78, 85, 107, 177, 129 } Session ID: 
>   {94, 94, 10, 23, 107, 225, 45, 207, 234, 219, 71, 87, 112, 37, 218,
>   175, 226, 249, 235, 229, 43, 149, 49, 236, 27, 116, 133, 118, 174, 68,
>   89, 148} Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   Compression Method: 0 Extension renegotiation_info,
>   renegotiated_connection:  Extension extended_master_secret
>   *** %% Initialized:  [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
>   ** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 update handshake state: server_hello[2] upcoming handshake states: server certificate[11]
>   upcoming handshake states: server_key_exchange12 upcoming
>   handshake states: certificate_request13 upcoming handshake
>   states: server_hello_done[14] upcoming handshake states: client
>   certificate11 upcoming handshake states:
>   client_key_exchange[16] upcoming handshake states:
>   certificate_verify15 upcoming handshake states: client
>   change_cipher_spec[-1] upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
>   upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1] upcoming
>   handshake states: server finished[20] check handshake state:
>   certificate[11] update handshake state: certificate[11] upcoming
>   handshake states: server_key_exchange12 upcoming handshake
>   states: certificate_request13 upcoming handshake states:
>   server_hello_done[14] upcoming handshake states: client
>   certificate11 upcoming handshake states:
>   client_key_exchange[16] upcoming handshake states:
>   certificate_verify15 upcoming handshake states: client
>   change_cipher_spec[-1] upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
>   upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1] upcoming
>   handshake states: server finished[20]
>   *** Certificate chain chain [0] = [ [   Version: V3   Subject: EMAILADDRESS=app-webserver@appdev.com, CN=app-webserver-commonName,
>   OU=app Demo, O=app cert, ST=CA, C=US   Signature Algorithm:
>   SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
>
> Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits   modulus:
>   10594925822321141887721258456061864128740466833580453489554475888747706649063995418909414161
>   public exponent: 65537   Validity: [From: Sat Feb 14 05:00:36 IST
>   2009,
>                  To: Tue Oct 23 06:47:16 IST 2040]   Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=app-webserver@appdev.com, CN=app-webserver-commonName,
>   OU=app Demo, O=app cert, ST=CA, C=US   SerialNumber: [    7cd0a83e
>   8bdfd29d]
>
> ]   Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]   Signature:  0060: 2A 78 FB 9B 2E EA 22
>   F5   A9 42 04 72 E3 45 4F 76  *x...."..B.r.EOv 0070: D9 38 F2 54 57 FA
>   AE 5F   42 CA FE 8C 5E 05 3E CE  .8.TW.._B...^.>.
>
> ]
>
> ---

```
XNIO-1 I/O-1, fatal error: 46: General SSLEngine problem

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]

XNIO-1 I/O-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown

XNIO-1 I/O-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

XNIO-1 I/O-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

XNIO-1 I/O-1, called closeOutbound()

XNIO-1 I/O-1, closeOutboundInternal()

org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available

at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:592)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the correct client jars? https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Developer_Guide.html#ejb

Comment: Yes, it works fine on http. Issue comes once ssl connection URL is configured. It shows following handhsake messages: upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]. But throws the exception after that. Any SSL settings needed in WF 16 remoting?

Comment: I never used SSL with EJB remoting because we used this for internal communication only

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using a valid certificate. Do you get a warning about the cert if you goto the server in your browser?

If you can't use a cert issued from a proper CA, then you will need to use a truststore with your client

Comment: It is a self signed certificate. I added the cert to client trust store but the same error. Anyway to get more details?

Comment: I don't think your truststore is functioning then. Can you show how you are using that?